# Show message until ajax response is received

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, delay, settimeout

I want to show an error message until the ajax response comes. Have tried with the following code:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "user.php",
      type: 'POST',
      data: $('#forgot-form').serialize(),
      beforeSend: function(){
         $('#error').html("Please wait until your request is processed.");
         setTimeout(function() { $("#error").html(''); }, 8000);
       }
     } ).done (function(data) { 
          /* I tried with the commented code also. But this section didn't worked */
          //$('#error').html("Please wait until your request is processed.");
          // setTimeout(function() { $("#error").html('Please wait until your request is processed.'); }, 8000);
          if (data == "success") {  
              $('#user-login').val('');
              $('#error').html("Please check your email to reset your password");
              setTimeout(function() { $("#error").html(''); }, 5000);   
              }  else if (data == "invalid") {

                         $('#error').html("Username or email doesnot exist");
                         setTimeout(function() { $("#error").html(''); }, 5000);
                         $('#user-login').focus();
                         return false;
                 }
         });
```

In *user.php* page, I am sending an email to the user if the user details are correct. So the response comes only late. Till that time I want to show waiting message.

This code shows the waiting message properly. But after that there is a small delay and then only shows success message. I need to avoid this time delay. How can I change the code so that the delay can be avoided?

Can anyone help me to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Just remove the `setTimeout()` from the before send call back. It will show msg in the #error and it will replace message after ajax complete.

```
 $.ajax({
          url: "user.php",
          type: 'POST',
          data: $('#forgot-form').serialize(),
          beforeSend: function(){
             $('#error').html("Please wait until your request is processed.");

           }
         } ).done (function(data) { 
              /* I tried with the commented code also. But this section didn't worked */
              //$('#error').html("Please wait until your request is processed.");
              // setTimeout(function() { $("#error").html('Please wait until your request is processed.'); }, 8000);
              if (data == "success") {  
                  $('#user-login').val('');
                  $('#error').html("Please check your email to reset your password");
                  setTimeout(function() { $("#error").html(''); }, 5000);   
                  }  
                  else if (data == "invalid") {

                             $('#error').html("Username or email doesnot exist");
                             setTimeout(function() { $("#error").html(''); }, 5000);
                             $('#user-login').focus();
                             return false;
                 }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `beforeSend()` and set the waiting message before `$.ajax` call.

```
 $('#error').html("Please wait until your request is processed.");
 $.ajax({
    url: "user.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('#forgot-form').serialize(),
 }).done (function(data) { 
    if (data == "success") {  
      $('#user-login').val('');
      $('#error').html("Please check your email to reset your password");
      setTimeout(function() { $("#error").html(''); }, 5000);   
    }  else if (data == "invalid") {
      $('#error').html("Username or email doesnot exist");
      setTimeout(function() { $("#error").html(''); }, 5000);
      $('#user-login').focus();
      return false;
    }
  });
```